# Graphviz - How to position label in the middle of a connection between nodes?

Tags: python, label, position, graphviz

I'm currently trying to make a mediation graphic using `graphviz` in python. As the title says, I got some problems in positioning a label in the middle of the connection of two nodes. I haven't found any example code for this problem yet.

```
from graphviz import Graph
from graphviz import render

dot = Graph(comment='test', engine='neato', node_attr={'shape': 'box'},
            edge_attr={'fontsize': '10'})

dot.node('Med', '', pos = '1,1!')
dot.node('UV', '', pos = '0,0!')
dot.node('AV', '', pos = '2,0!')

dot.edge('UV', 'AV', label='example a')
dot.edge('UV', 'Med', label='example a')
dot.edge('Med', 'AV', label='example a')

dot.save('./test.dot')

dot.render('./test_image.svg', view = True)

render('neato', 'svg', './test.dot')
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

The 'example' labels should be placed in the middle of the connections and also be parallel to the connections.

EDIT:

It was recommended by a user to use spaces in the label to position it. Here is what happens when I use spaces in "example a":

```
dot.edge('UV', 'AV', label='     example a')
```

[image]

Also, some extra arguments like xlabeland lp in dot.edge will not change anything in the labels position. There is no error message and the picure will be rendered as usual with the same label positions as before.

Comment: There are ways to tweak X/Y label positioning, but Graphviz does not support text at an angle (parallel to the edges)

Comment: I havn't figured out how to set the x/y positions. Do you have an example? 
And it would already help me to position it, the angle is just flavour ^^ The pos argument in the nodes also doesn't do anything in my code.. :/

Answer (score 1):

to tweak label positions:

- insert spaces and/or newlines into the label string to influence the label position e.g. `label="   my stuff"`
- try **xlabel** instead of **label** (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:xlabel)

to explicitly position labels (second try, first try was terribly incomplete):

- you need **pos** values for all nodes, edges, and labels (see https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)
- use the **lp** attribute to specify the X/Y position of the center of the label.  Remember that the units are points, not inches.  e.g. `x--y [... label="my stuff" lp="123,456" pos=...]`  (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:lp)
- then use the command **neato -n2** to generate your output

Here is an example (straight Graphviz, no python):

```
graph t {
    graph [bb="0,0,254,136"];
    node [label="\N",
        shape=box
    ];
    Med [height=0.5,
        pos="127,118",
        width=0.75];
    AV  [height=0.5,
        pos="227,18",
        width=0.75];
    Med -- AV   [label="example c",
        lp="140.56,75.442",
        lp="212.56,75.442",    // supersedes above
        pos="145.34,99.658 163.38,81.615 190.77,54.228 208.77,36.225"];
    UV  [height=0.5,
        pos="27,18",
        width=0.75];
    UV -- Med   [label="example b",
        lp="40.058,75.558",
        pos="45.342,36.342 63.385,54.385 90.772,81.772 108.77,99.775"];
    UV -- AV    [label="example a",
        lp="90.665,25.5",
        lp="127.665,25.5",  // supersedes above
        pos="54.39,18 92.689,18 161.82,18 199.94,18"];
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input :) I tried using spaces and got.... weird.. outputs. With different spaces the label changes completly its position. 

I also tried adding lp as an extra attribute. But unfortunalty, nothing happens. I don't get an error output, the argument just gets ignored. Same with the xlabel. I update the post with some pictures of what happens when I use spaces.